# Ember - Sending particular values in PUT request

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a form which I am using to edit details via form. Ember does a PUT request like required but I need it to only send particular values and not everything within the JSON object. The object is structured as:

```
{
  consoles: {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Street Fighter",
    "type":"Beat-em-up"
    "versions": "10",
    "consoles": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "console": "Xbox 360"
      },{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "console": "Xbox One"
      },{
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Sony",
        "console": "Playstation 4"
      }
    ],
    "Characters":[],
    "Reviews":[]
  }
}
```

The only editable values within my form are:

- name
- type
- versions

When I press the update button, everything is sent in a PUT request. Is it possible for **ONLY** name, type and versions to be sent in the request?

I'm aware of overriding updateRecord but I wouldn't know where to start if this was what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own `Serializer` to only send specific attributes up to the server.

See the docs [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize)

Comment: Thanks for you help Kalman. This is the second time you've helped me. Again much appreciated.